# Suppose $\epsilon = a + b \sqrt d$ a unit in $R=\Bbb Z [\sqrt d] = \{a+b\sqrt d : a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$ . Proof that $\pm a\pm b \sqrt {d}$ are units.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve some problems for my ring theory exam. I have problems solving this one:

> Let $d\in \Bbb Z_{>0}$ such that $d$ is not a square. Suppose
>    $\epsilon = a + b \sqrt d$ a unit in $$R=\Bbb Z [\sqrt d] = \{a+b\sqrt
>  d : a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$$
>
> Proof that $\pm a\pm b \sqrt {d}$ are units. Show that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt
>  5]$ contains infinite many units.

Hints or a detailed proof are both really appreciated.

Comment: Do you see why it is enough to show that $a - b\sqrt{d}$ is a unit?

Comment: Hint: Automorphisms preserve units.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If $a-b\sqrt d$ is a unit, then $-a + b \sqrt d$ is a unit. I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg No idea what that has to do with it.

Comment: Have you learned about norms and how they relate to units?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No, this an exercise in the first chapter of ring theory. I only now a couple of definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a + b\sqrt{d}$ is a unit means we can find $a', b' \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$(a + b\sqrt{d})(a' + b'\sqrt{d} ) = 1$. However, this implies
$$\begin{cases}a a' + b b' d & = 1\\ a b'+ b a' & = 0\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
(a - b\sqrt{d})(a' - b'\sqrt{d} ) = 1
$$
and hence $a - b \sqrt{d}$ is a unit. One can show other combination $\pm a \pm b \sqrt{d}$ are units using similar arguments.

About the part $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ contains infinitely many units. You need to use/show two things:

1. $a + b\sqrt{d}$, $a' + b'\sqrt{d}$ are units $\quad\implies\quad (a + b\sqrt{d})(a' + b'\sqrt{d})$ is a unit.
2. find a unit $a + b\sqrt{5}$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ and verify $(a + b\sqrt{5})^n, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ are all distinct.

Comment: why do you prove $(a+b\sqrt{d})(a′+b′\sqrt{d})=1$. i can have distinct d's right, so shouldn't I prove:$(a+bsqrt{d})(a′+b′\sqrt{d'})=1$?

Comment: No, it should be the same $d$. That is a crucial thing to understand from the outset.

Comment: @KeesTil Haha, ik zag ook net. Super dom. Die $d$ staat gewoon vast. Gewoon per definitie. Alleen $a$, en $b$ varieren.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible line of attack: (1) Suppose $a + b\sqrt{d}$ is a unit, i.e., has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. How would you find the inverse $\frac1{a + b\sqrt{d}}$? Remember "rationalizing the denominator". (2) Based on this, what criteria must be satisfied for an inverse to exist? (3) Show these criteria are met for $a - b\sqrt{d}$ if they are met for $a + b\sqrt{d}$.

Comment: I get that in both cases both $a$ and $b$ must be divisble by $a^2-b^2d$. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, and now use this to clinch the argument, as in (3)!

Comment: If $a+b\sqrt d$ is invertible, then $a$ and $b$ are divisble by $a^2-b^2d$.  Then $a$ and $-b$ are also divsible by $a^2-b^2d$. Therefore $a-b\sqrt d$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for 1st task would be to use the norm on $Z[\sqrt{5}]$ (denote  $d(\epsilon) =d(a+b\sqrt{5})=|a^2 -5b^2|$):
$d(\epsilon)\cdot d(x)=(*)=d(\epsilon\cdot x)=d(1)=1$. 
This implies $d(\epsilon)=1$, thus $|a^2 -5b^2|=1$, thus $a^2 -5b^2=\pm 1$.

a) $a^2 -5b^2=1$ implies $(a+b\sqrt{5})(a-b\sqrt{5})=1$, i.e. $a-b\sqrt{5}$ is unit  with inverse $a+b\sqrt{5}$

b) $a^2 -5b^2=-1$ would mean that the unit is $-(a-b\sqrt{5})=-a+b\sqrt{5}$.

Clearly, the remaining $a$ and $b$ combinations would result in both cases (a) and b)) just from the change of sign.

Step (*) can be easily proven.